# How can i get option number from an DHCP header in scapy?

Tags: python, dhcp, scapy

I have an DHCP packet received. I want to obtain the number of the option from that packet. E.g. server_id option has number 53. I need to do this in scapy.

I tried `if pkt[DHCP].options[i] == 53: do something` but dosen't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Options field are a tuples. To acces a value of an option you have to use

```
if pkt[DHCP].options[i][j] == 53: do something
```

where i -is the number of the option(starts from 0) and j - is the value or the name of the option(j=0 is the name, and j=1 is the value).